# Is it proper to change time signature for one measure?

Tags: time-signatures

I am trying to write down some music that I've made and I have this problem: some parts require a change in time signature in order the phrase to fit, just for one or two measures. It can go from 4/4 to 5/4 or 3/4 and back again. Is this common or am I writing irrational music? Any thoughts are welcomed.

It is music for one guitar, no beat.

Comment: What do you mean by "irrational"? What exactly are you concerned about? When you perform the music, do you like how it sounds? Are you particularly concerned about expressing a particular rhythm?

Comment: Yes I like the way it sounds but I am concerned if someone try to reproduce it from sheet if he will be able to do it

Comment: Would you really change your music just because you're concerned that other players may find it too difficult to read?  What is your objective with this piece of music?  An artistic creation, or something else (like a didactic piece for teaching students?).

Comment: This is why I made the original question, to help me figure out how to fit the sheet music rules to the actual music not the other way around. My objective is artistic creation written properly so other people can play it

Comment: Ah, so your question is not about whether or not the music as you've written is "proper" in any artistic sense, but whether your decision to notate it as a one-measure time signature change is idiomatic, or whether there might perhaps be a more natural way to notate the same phrase?  In other words, this question is strictly about *how to notate* the musical phrase you have written?

Comment: Okay, but that leaves the question - is there a particular rhythm to it, some repeating pattern? What, conceptually, is the *reason* for the irregular beats? What kind of mood are you trying to create?

Comment: Irrational would be pi or e quarter notes per measure...

Comment: Yes, my question is about how to notate a piece of music that i have made without compromise it in favor of rules. It has a pattern, the bottom /4 doesn't change but the length of the measure, the upper 4/ changes, that's the way the song is written. It's a world music type, very few of that kind have ever be written, I don't know any examples, that's why i need to ask more knowledgeable than me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is very acceptable. There is plenty of music out there that changes time signatures very quickly in a very short amount of time. For instance, Stravinsky's *Rite of Spring* has some passages in which the time signature changes every measure, and not just from 4/4 to 5/5 to 3/4 to 4/4--sometimes it is 2/16 to 3/8 to 3/4, and such chaotic shifts like this.

I wouldn't be too worried about it, so long as your phrases and melodies don't sound too 'jolting'--unless that's the intent you have.

Comment: It is also relevant to note that many much music that does note explicitly change time signatures does change change it _experientially_. Much of classical music feature brief time signature changes that are clearly audible but are not, nonetheless, notated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it motivates me to keep going

Comment: [Some people might argue](https://youtu.be/quOLtE0wfAo?t=532) that Stravinsky did _not_ use the right tool when he wrote those time signatures, though: that the whole thing should be approached from something based on _additive meter_. But, I definitely agree that a single odd measure isn't anything to worry about at all.

Comment: @FelipeMartins Are you talking about brief, un-notated changes of the _length_ and/or stress of beats (which would be perfectly normal in many types of music), or of their _number_ (which I don't think would)?

Comment: @gidds The first option, in the case where those changes are sufficient to alter our perception of the underlying meter.

Comment: For a less "chaotic" example than *Rite of Spring*, see Mussorgsky's *Pictures at an Exhibition*, specifically the Promenade sections, which bounce around between 4/4, 5/4, 6/4, and 7/4, and yet still sound like a regular, stately march.  You barely even notice that it's changing meter almost every measure when just casually listening.

Answer (score 4):

You said "no beat" so are you forcing it into a specific time signature?

Sounds to me like you're writing in **Free Time**  or **Unmetered Time**
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_time_(music) 
 This would free you from picking a time signature at any point (pun not intended)

There is no requirement to have a time signature if your piece doesn't suit one, however it may help a future reader to comprehend the sheet music.  You can annotate it "rhythm without beat" which means to not accent the first note of a bar.

Free time can use stave lines to delineate a measure, regardless of length.  You can still have a tempo to indicate a speed too.

Related: [Free time in music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/54605/free-time-in-music)

Comment: No beat I mean no percussion instruments or something to give me the measure, I have beat, the bottom is /4. Very interesting information about the free time, I had no idea

Answer (score 1):

It depends if that is what you mean or not :)

There is no such thing as 'irrational' music - just music you like and music you don't. The question is really about what's easiest to read. You could try using a piano roll editor to define exactly what you mean to play by ear, and then see how the DAW software interprets what you have written given different signature descriptions. This won't tell you what's 'right' or 'wrong', but it may help to 'find' a simpler way of writing what you mean.

If it's going to be really difficult to read and accuracy matters to you, provide an 'unsung' lyric that defines the rhythm: Drummers learn complex patterns this way.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that common, but it's not unacceptable either. The first beat of any bar, 3/4, 4/4, 5/4 etc., is usually the most emphasised - if that feel doesn't come across, maybe the time signature isn't correct.

So, yes, change the time signature for one bar, or two, as that's the way most 'irrational' music gets written. You *could* stick to say, 4/4 and write accents over the notes that would otherwise become 1st beats in new bars - that is another ploy used by some composers - but then you must be aware that the first beats will still have emphases. Probably best to change time signatures, and write emphases as and when needed as well. Also be aware that if the 'beat' continues in rhythm, the bottom 4 will reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for the information, the bottom 4 remains, it is the length of the measure that changes, this need time to sink